# Format a requirements.txt file for pip where one or more packages have a different index-url

Tags: python, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku where one of the required packages lives on `https://testpypi.python.org/pypi` and of course Django is on the main PyPI server.

The `requirements.txt` file looks like so:

```
Django==1.7.7
-i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
foo-bar==0.4
```

running `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails with the following error:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

So it looks like `pip` is trying to find Django on `testpypi`

So I tried this:

```
-i https://pypi.python.org/pypi/
Django==1.7.7
-i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
foo-bar==0.4
```

It results in the same error.

If I place just one (doen't matter witch one) of packages in the requirements file pip is able to find the package and install it.

**Question:** What is the correct syntax for specifying multiple different `index-url` arguments within a single file that can be read by the command `pip install -r file`

I don't think it matters but python is version 3.4.0 and pip is version `pip 1.5.2`.

I have updated pip to version 6.0.8, error now reads as:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
No distributions at all found for Django==1.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By definition, any private index definition will apply to every package

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#private-indexes

> All dependencies specified in that requirements file will resolve against that index.

As a workaround, you can create multiple requirements files and cascade them:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#cascading-requirements-files

> If you would like to utilize multiple requirements files in your codebase, you can include the contents of another requirements file with pip:
>
> `-r ./path/to/prod-requirements.txt`

**Update**: It turns out that the correct method of dealing with private indexes is to use `--extra-index-url` switch. From the [documentation of pip](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#indexes-find-links):

> Note that using --index-url removes the use of PyPI, while using --extra-index-url will add additional indexes.

So, putting the line

```
--extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/
```

on top of your `requirements.txt` should be enough. No need to cascade at all!